# Terminal exit without performing action

Tags: applescript

I've made a script which have a block of code launching Terminal to retrieve picture from a server, using FTP.

When I run the script under the script editor, everything is OK: the script launch the Terminal, open the FTP session, set the destination path, get the files, delete them from the server, close connexion, wait the end of Terminal activty and then quit.

But when I run my Script as application, in about 90% of cases, the app launch Terminal and then Terminal quit immediatly. When the Terminal seems to "get" correctly the FTP commands, connexion is done, getting file and so on. Perfectly. But this happens only in a few cases.

Here the last code I have for this part:

```
  tell application "Terminal"
    activate

    -- Wait for "no more activity"
    set frontWindow to window 1
    repeat until busy of frontWindow is false
        delay 1
    end repeat

    -- Perform FTP actins
    set shell to do script "ftp -i ftp://user_ftp:pass_ftp@host_ftp/" in window 1
    do script "lcd ~/Desktop/tmp_instagram/" in shell
    do script "mget *.jpg" in shell
    do script "mdel *.jpg" in shell
    do script "bye" in shell
    -- Wait for no more activity
    set frontWindow to window 1
    repeat until busy of frontWindow is false
        delay 1
    end repeat

end tell

tell application "Terminal" to quit saving no -- Saving no to avoid conf alert
```

For avoiding you to loose your time, here are some of the tests I've made, without any success:

- Setting the whole FTP command in one line so.
- Put a delay 5 after the ativate, rather than the repeat on busy
- Put a delay after the ftp command

In fact, the Terminal seems to close before receiving the FTP command (opened and closed immediatly).

Comment: Why are you even starting Terminal?

Comment: @Mark directly using shell d'ont work. But I suppose there is a conflict between set shell and the fact Terminal is open. I've found  better option: not use shell but perform so do script under Terminal and it seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark Setchell comment I tried without using the "shell" command and in fact it seems to be the key. Here is a piece of code which run correctly:

```
    tell application "Terminal"
    activate

    set w to window frontmost
    do script "ftp -i ftp://xxxxx:yy@dddddd/" in w
    do script "lcd ~/Desktop/tmp_aarecno_instagram/" in w
    do script "mget *.jpg" in w
    do script "mdel *.jpg" in w
    do script "bye" in w

    set frontWindow to window 1
    repeat until busy of frontWindow is false
        delay 1
    end repeat

end tell
```